# How to show ALL the invalid options entered when getopts is used?

Tags: shell, switch-statement, parameter-passing, getopts

I have written a script `myscript`:

```
while getopts "t:" opt; do
  case ${opt} in
    t )
      target=$OPTARG
      ;;
   
    * )
      echo "Invalid option: $OPTARG requires an argument" 
      exit 1;
      ;;
  esac
done
shift $((OPTIND -1))
```

If I enter an input like

```
$ myscript -eio
```

It ONLY displays

```
Invalid option: e
```

I want it to display all of the INVALID options I passed, like:

```
Invalid option: e
Invalid option: i
Invalid option: o
```

I've used `exit 1` to exit the script showing invalid options and I don't want the script to execute any further.But if I don't use it, it'll show ALL  the invalid options HOW I WANT but, the  script will execute further, which I **don't** want.

Please do help. Thanks.

Comment: I did mention in the end as to WHY I should use the exit 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a helper variable, `invalid` that records any invalid option. Once the option parsing loop is done, test it.

```
invalid=false
while getopts "t:" opt; do
  case ${opt} in
    (t)
      target=$OPTARG
      ;;
   
    (*)
      echo "Invalid option: $OPTARG requires an argument" 
      invalid=true
      ;;
  esac
done
case $invalid in
   (true) exit 1;;
esac

shift $((OPTIND -1))
```

Comment: Super awesome. Works exactly how I want. Thanks a lot! ✅